# Swift UIWebView constraints full screen

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I have these constraints for my UIWebView:

```
 let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

My question is, how do I get the width and height constraint to be full device screen? I have to do this programmatically

Answer (score 6):

Use this constraints for a full screen mode:

```
let topConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let botConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let leftConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let rigthConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConst,botConst,leftConst,rigthConst])

self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

webview is the view that I wanted to be in full screen. Don't forget to set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false after activate the constraints.